# Typescript Property 'length' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and have been trying to get the following snippet to work:

```
quoteService.getQuoteOfTheDay()
        .then(quotes => this.quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]);
```

The idea is to randomly select a quote from the array.

Instead I get the following error in Terminal `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Quote'.`

If I change `quotes.length` to `4` the snippet works but I want to the function to figure out how many quotes there are and then randomly return a single one.

Here is the entire Component below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Quote } from './quote.model';
import { QuoteService } from './quote.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [QuoteService]
})

export class AppComponent {

    title = 'App is running!';
    quote: Quote;

    constructor(quoteService: QuoteService) {

      quoteService.getQuoteOfTheDay()
        .then(quotes => this.quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]);

    }
}
```

The **quote.service.ts** was wrong

```
getQuoteOfTheDay(): Promise<Quote> {
    return this.http.get('quote.json').toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Should have been like this

```
getQuoteOfTheDay(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('quote.json').toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Probably the return type of `getQuoteOfTheDay` is wrong. It should be `Promise<[Quote]>` not `Promise<Quote>`. Please show us the definition of that function.

Comment: @Bergi I fixed it by changing `Promise<Quote>` to `Promise<any>`

Comment: That's worse actually. If you expect it to fulfill with an array of quotes, you should declare that so.

Comment: Using any == "TypeScript -  you're doing it wrong"

Comment: @Bergi changed it to your suggestion I hadn't noticed the `[]` wrap around `Quote` Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type for `getQuoteOfTheDay(): Promise<Quote>` seems to be wrong. While the method name, method type and file name all suggest that the returned promise will fulfill with only a single quote, your component is using it as if it returned an array of quotes. You'll want to use

```
getQuotesOfTheDay(): Promise<[Quote]> {
//      ^                    ^     ^
    return this.http.get('quotes.json').toPromise()
//                             ^
        .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using quotes[].length since it appears to be an array.

Comment: if `quotes` is an array, then `quotes[]` is... not anything.